# scp - lack of consistency

Tags: directory, scp

I've observed a strange behaviour copying files from a remote server with `scp`.
I had a directory containing many subdirectories with files.

```
directory
├── directory1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
├── directory2
│   ├── file3.txt
```

So, I used `scp`: `scp -r <server_address_n_path_to_directory> <output_dir>`.

- When `output_dir` existed, all the directories structure and files inside `directory` were properly copied.
- But, when I forgot to create the `output_dir`, only the files from all the subdirectories were copied to the newly created by `scp` folder.

I tested this a few times with the same result.

Is it an inconsistency or an intentional behaviour?
What's a reason?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Which version of OpenSSH?

Comment: possibly related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344410/17683